# How to scrape a live stock price from a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract the live price of this stock and storing it as a variable.

**This is my code**

```
import re

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request("https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xc001bbe2b87079294c63ece98bdd0a88d761434e", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

webpage = urlopen(req).read()

page = urlopen(req)

html_bytes = page.read()

html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")

s = "THE HTML BELLOW"

extractTheNumber = re.findall('(\d+?)\s', s)

print(extractTheNumber[0])
```

**This is the site with the price :**
https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xc001bbe2b87079294c63ece98bdd0a88d761434e

**This is the html for the variable 's':**

```
span class="text-success"
```

(but add the <> on each end )

I have no clue where to go from here or why it doesnt work.

Comment: why don't you include the error message as well? there's a lot of _possible_ problems here...

Comment: the main problem is probably the fact that you're looking inside a silly constant string s, not inside the html which you would want to do

Comment: I think your request returns insufficient data, as the actual webpage relies on some JS render the data. My suggestion for you would be to look into Selenium for this task.